# IOException was unhandled with System.IO.FileSystemWatcher feature

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

Basically what I'm trying to do is watch for new files that get put into a folder with a specific file extention (*.req) so I started setting up using the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher feature.  So after I started my program, I simply copy a group of *.req files into my watched folder and they seem to run fine the first time without any errors.  The files subsequently get renamed, processed, then deleted.  I would subsequently re-copy the same *.req files over and now this time it blows an IOException was unhandled error as follows in detail:

```
    System.IO.IOException was unhandled
    HResult=-2147024864
    Message=The process cannot access the file 'C:\accucom\reqdir\hcd - Copy (2).req' because it is being used by another process.
    Source=mscorlib
    StackTrace:
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
    at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
    at CollectV2.CollectV2.OnChanged(Object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) in C:\accucom\CollectV2\CollectV2.cs:line 375
    at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.OnCreated(FileSystemEventArgs e)
    at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(Int32 action, String name)
    at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* overlappedPointer)
    at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
    InnerException:
```

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using as I wonder what I may be missing here:

```
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = GlobalVars.REQpath;
        // Only watch *.req files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.req";
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait for the user to quit the program.
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;

    // Define the event handlers. 
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
        string rqfile = e.FullPath.Replace(".req", ".re0");
        //System.IO.File.Delete(rqfile);
        System.IO.File.Copy(e.FullPath, rqfile);
        System.IO.File.Delete(e.FullPath);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(wcbdoRequestFile, rqfile);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in these lines:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(e.FullPath, rqfile);
System.IO.File.Delete(e.FullPath);
```

I'm guessing that the problem is that you respond to a file being changed while the process changing it still has it opened.

The ideal solution is for the program that is changing the file to inform your program when it has finished with the file and has closed it.

Failing that, the only way I've found is to repeatedly try the copy/delete operation until it succeeds, waiting for a short while between each attempt. That's not very nice of course, but without being able to communicate with the other program it may be all you can do.

Comment: The original way I had this was to keep reading the directory of the folder for any *.req files with a sleep(250) in between using the following command:

files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(GlobalVars.REQpath, "*.req", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

The problem I was having is the path is on a network folder where client programs can place it, but I've noticed it can take 5-6 seconds before this dedicated server actually sees the files using this method, so I'm looking for perhaps a quicker way if possible, and must work ultimately without error.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following code which avoided me getting errors but still don't understand  why it had to wait for some process to finish:

```
        System.IO.File.Delete(rqfile);
        while (true) {
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(e.FullPath, rqfile);
                break;
            }
            catch { }
        }
        System.IO.File.Delete(e.FullPath);
```